# Convert one Vlookup formula to array formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

i am using a vlook up formula in my sheet. i need to apply array formula instead of that. pls help me to convert this formula to array formula.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,FILTER('Individual'!$C$3:E,'Individual'!$C$3:$C=A2),3,1))
```

this one gives the latest values against the code

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3:A, FILTER(Individual!C3:E, 
 REGEXMATCH(Individual!C3:C, "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, A3:A)&"$")), 3, 0)))
```

[image]

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3:A, Individual!C3:E, 3, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

**for latest price:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3:A, 
 QUERY(SORTN(SORT(Individual!A3:E, 1, 0), 9^9, 2, 3, 1), 
 "select Col3,Col5", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks.. but for your kind info, my individual sheet is seperated by a blank row for seperating values by week. for eg: after putting the values for a week. i leave a blank row before putting values for another week. in that case. this formula gives #N/A

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10fxGKhiBwFfv1osdwTI3wu8i3knqmKQKHC8V1ffca5M/edit#gid=0 pls take a look

Comment: no bro y u changed filter ? my formula gives me the latest price against the code.